# Метод qsort не вызывает compare

Tags: c, qsort

Пишу программу на си, по непонятной мне причине функция qsort не вызывает функцию compare.

strings, соответственно, массив char**.

```
qsort(strings, sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0]), sizeof(char*), compare);

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char * one = * (char **) a;
    char * two = * (char **) b;

    return strcmp(one,two);

}
```

Comment: Как вы определили, что не вызывает?

Comment: Если ставить print statements первой строкой compare - оно не вызывается

Comment: Нашла проблему, думаю над решением: поскольку strings - char**, sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0]) дает неверный ответ.

Comment: Именно поэтому в вопросе нужно сразу давать *полный* код, чтобы мы просто так голову не ломали. Решение - хранить длину массива отдельно. Если массив - параметр функции, передавать длину другим параметром.

Comment: Спасибо, так сейчас и делаю. Думала, нет ли более изящного решения. 

Про полный код - я упоминаю формат strings в вопросе, а полный код длинный и неимеющий отношения к вопросу. 

Еще раз спасибо. Если запишите это ответом - могу принять сейчас.

Comment: Пардон, проглядел. Не, ответ нашли вы - вам его и писать. :) Есть еще вариант решения - заканчивать массив нулевым указателем. Но тогда эту длину нужно будет каждый раз определять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась во втором переданном параметре: поскольку формат strings char**, выражение sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0]) будет всегда возвращать 1, так как оба значения в выражении - pointers. 
Решением может быть подсчет строк заранее и передача этого числа в качестве параметра.

Comment: Но и с третьим параметром у Вас не всё гладко. Проще говоря, второй параметр - **количество**  блоков для сортировки, а третий - **размер** такого блока. *sizeof(char*)* - это 4. Всегда! А сортируете Вы, насколько я понял, строки, которые могут иметь разную длину. Или всё-таки указатели на строки?

Comment: @Sergey Судя по компаратору - все-таки указатели.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вроде - да... Но TS как-то не очень внятно об этом говорит.

Comment: @Sergey А подскажите неопытным, что такое TS?

Comment: @Maria Lifshits TS - Topic Starter -тот, кто всю бодягу и заварил :-)